# Print out returned data from API using VueJS 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to print a simple JSON object that is returned via my API in VueJS.

Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 align="center">Test</h1>
    <p>Received response from the API : {{ coreResp }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {login} from "@/services/core-api";
import {useAuth0} from "@auth0/auth0-vue";

let coreResp

const get = async () => {
  const {getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0();
  const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
  coreResp = await login(accessToken)
};

get();
</script>
```

If I console.log `coreResp` I get

```
data: {Message: 'successfully authenticated via Auth0'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

However, when I run the app and view the component there is nothing on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your UI updated with API data, you need to use `ref`.

Once `ref` is updated the UI will re-render, unlike regular variables it will not update the UI when it changed.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 align="center">Test</h1>
    <p>Received response from the API : {{ coreResp }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {login} from "@/services/core-api";
import {useAuth0} from "@auth0/auth0-vue";
import { ref } from 'vue';

const coreResp = ref('Loading data ....');

const get = async () => {
  const {getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0();
  const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
  coreResp.value = await login(accessToken)
};

get();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) to make it reactive.

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
let coreResp = ref('');
// ...
coreResp.value = await login(accessToken);
```